# Google App Engine and android

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am new to android development and finding it difficult to understand some topics. I intend to develop a polling app where I want to post questions from my server which gets updated in the app and responses from users get stored in my online database. I do not want any Web interface of my application.

I know how to create an android app using eclipse, android sdk and ADT.
Also after reading on web I understand I need backend to be Google App Engine for my server and Database(I need external database).

1)My first problem is people use python to develop appengine side code and I do not know python, I just know basic of java(by android programming), so should I use appengine SDK for Java?

2) Do i necessarily need to install "Google plugin for eclipse" for coding server side program, or just the appengine sdk would do? The plugin has a feature of "App engine connected android project" , Is it very useful?

3)I read that I need to use GWT SDK for programming of webapp with GAE, but as i said I don't want any web interface, will i require GWT?

Any help regarding how to proceed for my application will be very useful.
Thank You.

Comment: I am voting down because I felt that you skimmed through the documentation instead of reading it and trying it out .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure where  you get all these misconceptions from let me clarify them one by one

1. First of all There is no need to use GAE for an android app's backend, The backend any be anything that emits data in a parsable format . So you can use `JSP` , `Node.js`, `Ruby on Rails`, `Asp.Net` or any other web framework that suits your need.
2. Just like you can use any web framework you can also use any database that works for you.

> My first problem is people use python to develop appengine side code
>   and I do not know python, I just know basic of java(by android
>   programming), so should I use appengine SDK for Java?

If you want to develop with Java for GAE, go ahead, Its just servlets with a few restrictions.

> 2) Do i necessarily need to install "Google plugin for eclipse" for
>   coding server side program, or just the appengine sdk would do? The
>   plugin has a feature of "App engine connected android project" , Is it
>   very useful?

Installing Google plugin is optional, you can build it using ant builds.
As for the appengine connected android project, Give it a shot, I does help. But whether it suits your needs or not, is for you to decide after trying it out.

> 3)I read that I need to use GWT SDK for programming of webapp with
>   GAE, but as i said I don't want any web interface, will i require GWT?

Using GWT is completely optional with GAE. Use it only if you need it.