# Architecture of a Mobile Survey App

Tags: mobile, architecture

I am about to initiate a mobile app for surveys. There will be 2 users: **Surveyor** and the **Survey_Taker**. A surveyor would design the survey and send it to the survey taker. The survey taker completes the survey and send it back to the surveyor.

Now would i need to host a database on the web to sync the data from the survey taker's mobile to send  it back to the surveyor.Or can i do without it?

Wonder if i can send the survey with the functionality to store the survey data in a text file ? What would be the consequences then ?

Comment: Is the surveyor also using a/the mobile app to view results or is the app desktop/web based?

Comment: @Raul The surveyor is suppose to recieve and the filled up surveys via his/her mobile. These will be sent by the survey taker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a thin server responsible for storing and aggregating some report data.
Having a server to sync between client types would prove to be more robust.
Storing can be done in files, say JSON format. Alternatively, depending on the scaling needs, storage can be switched to NoSQL db.
To start quickly, you can have a Node.js server.

Comment: So what you mean is: "Once the survey is receined on the client's phone and the client fills it up, the entered values are stored in a flat file in JSON format. And then this data is fetched to the DB (NoSQL db) hosted on the server". Please confirm and correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I guess my point is having a (NoSQL) DB is a matter of scalability rather than design. You can do fine without one. Regarding the method on how the survey gets from the person taking it and the person viewing it is through the server. Store the survey on the server and pass it to the client. The surveyor app can poll the server for new results. Hope this helps.

Comment: Right! Another Option: Can i design my surveys being receved or sent as email body/attachment (HTML5/CSS) ?

Comment: Would you care to shed some light on the right answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391792/google-app-engine-and-android

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative for taking surveys is using Google Forms 
http://www.labnol.org/software/google-docs-forms-for-surveys/10056/

Ensures:

- good viewing on mobile devices
- sending email with results

Comment: That is indeed a very inexpensive way to develop a survey app. Wonder if Google Docs helps in reporting as well?

Comment: Yes, Goolge Forms has support for survey analisys. http://www.mattsilverman.com/2008/10/introduction-to-google-forms.html

Answer (score 4):

You can perfectly do without a database, for example by sending the survey results via e-mail to the surveyor. However, it might be a bit uncomfortable to analyze results. Therefore, your need for a database is mainly determined by your reporting requirements. So: what do you want to do with the data?

Comment: I would like to represent the data in charts and graphs.

Answer (score 4):

Being a mobile application, I would definitely consider the following features:

- Bookmark a survey
- Store the survey in my mobile phone for later completion
- Answer the survey offline
- Send the survey to the server
- Reconciliate the received survey (in case the survey's questions have changed in the meantime)

That been said, I would use a local (file?) storage on the mobile and a DB on the server.

Comment: Is there any other substitute for a DB on the server? Can i do with out it?

Comment: Can't i simple use email and a flat file?

Comment: Can't i design my surveys in javascript. And then sen it to the survey_taker via email body/attachment ? Can you guide me on this option.

Comment: Maxood, sorry for replying so late - yes, you can indeed use flat files and emails, but then you have to produce more code to digest these e-mails / files and produce the reporting you need.

It really boils down to what your requirements are. Nowadays you can get a MySQL instance virtually for free, so I don't quite get how a file could be an easier take at this problem. If you want a FORM to be posted using a file, many hosting services already do this for you for free using CGI scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Small questions first:

Yes you can use text file, though I think JSON is simpler. It's human-readable when pretty-printed, unambiguous and safe from special characters.

You can have your own simple RESTful database, you can use some large app site (google sites / fb / etc), you can even send emails back and forth, that's up to you.

Client-side you want HTML5.

However, the most important aspect (*) of your system is usability for the most users -- survey takers.

Consider this horrible example:

```
What is your age:
[ ] between 1 and 5
[ ] between 6 and 10
etc.
```

Then consider this, an absolute survey killer:

```
How much do you agree with the following:
                          not at all / not really / neutral / somewhat / a lot
My cat likes red              [ ]        [ ]          [ ]        [ ]      [ ]
Eggs are better than ham      [ ]        [ ]          [ ]        [ ]      [ ]
I don't take a bus            [ ]        [ ]          [ ]        [ ]      [ ]
I hate politics               [ ]        [ ]          [ ]        [ ]      [ ]
Fish is expensive             [ ]        [ ]          [ ]        [ ]      [ ]
Pollution is good             [ ]        [ ]          [ ]        [ ]      [ ]
Manager helped me a lot       [ ]        [ ]          [ ]        [ ]      [ ]
Repairman was not helpful     [ ]        [ ]          [ ]        [ ]      [ ]
Supervisor knows his shit     [ ]        [ ]          [ ]        [ ]      [ ]
Salesmen were friendly        [ ]        [ ]          [ ]        [ ]      [ ]
Office smells and looks nice  [ ]        [ ]          [ ]        [ ]      [ ]
```

First, your users are overwhelmed with choices, and many give up

Then some confuse which box refers to which question

Then some don't get double negation "do not agree with repairman not helpful"

Eventually the only users who complete your survey are those who picked random answers and a few who have really strong feelings. Either way the results are pure rubbish -- randomness mixed with exaggeration.

Now consider a better designed survey interace:

```
What was your impression?
[smiley]<====[slider]====>[angry]

How far do you live from our store?
[house]<=====[slider]=====>[mountain]

# slider icon changes as you drag it:
# house/block/road/highway/city/mountain
```

When your surveys are quick and to the point, you will get a lot more answers.

There's a lot more that goes in a good survey, e.g. questions should not be suggestive (how much did you *like* our service?), questions have to be unambiguous (how is our new section?), questions cannot be too personal (when did you child die?) etc. I guess many books are written on this subject, but you cannot easily enforce this in your system.

(*) I'm assuming average users who choose to participate in your surveys, I discount cases where users are forced to participate, e.g. school exams.

Comment: The question is specifically about what should be the ideal architecture of the survey application on a mobile platform and not how a typical survey should look like! Although, i do value your feedback here regarding USABILITY. Remember, that in any product lifecyle the questions that comes first are "WHAT" and "WHY"....and then comes "HOW"!

Comment: I would highly appreciate if you can elaborate the first 6 lines of your answer. Thanks

Comment: Consider text file format like this: `question="how far?" options="1,2,3"` now imagine some customer asks `how far to "HYD"?` and you end up with `question="how far to "ICT"?" ...`, which you cannot parse anymore. you will have to invent your own escape sequences, etc. That's why it's better to stick to existing format, JSON or ini file.

Comment: You have a choice -- set up own server, or use existing server for hire, e.g. virtual server on amazon or set up a company page on fb, or make an app on g app engine. the latter is easier, scales out of the box, etc. this choice restricts your options for communication protocol, so read up on the implications. If in doubt, start with app engine, it's basically free until your app becomes popular.

Comment: Gotcha! Here's something i have found quite valuable here and relevant  to my question and app requirement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391792/google-app-engine-and-android

Answer (score 0):

For mobile survey please check http://askmeqr.com - it's mobile version of Google Forms generator.